# R: cannot use functions after install_github

Tags: r, package, install.packages

I ran `install_github('zhangyuqing/sva-devel')` (recommended here: https://github.com/jtleek/sva-devel/issues/14) but cannot run the function `ComBat()` afterwards, getting shows `Error in ComBat() : could not find function "ComBat"`.

More generally put, how do I do in R what `import sva-devel` does in Python?

I tried

````
> library('sva')
Error in library("sva") : there is no package called ‘sva’
> library('sva-devel')
Error in library("sva-devel") : there is no package called ‘sva-devel’```
````

Comment: That error is indicating `sva` didn't get installed.

Comment: The sva package is not installed. Was there an error message when you ran the `install_github` function?

Comment: Damn. Sometimes all one needs is to just know that things are really supposed to work. I just tried installing it again with the same command and now library('sva')  works. Can't see anymore that went wrong in the previous install because I had a bunch of other output since